# How to group/split array of objects by weeks with start and end date

Tags: reactjs, sorting, foreach, group-by, lodash

I have big array of objects.

```
let objectsList = [
    {name: 'Misha', surname: 'Borovuk', id: '1', createdProfile: '11/02/2022'}
    {name: 'Karina', surname: 'Burba', id: '2', createdProfile: '17/01/2022'}
    {name: 'Alina', surname: 'Shulan', id: '3', createdProfile: '05/01/2021'}
    {name: 'Sasha', surname: 'Uena', id: '4', createdProfile: '11/02/2021'}
    {name: 'Stepan', surname: 'German', id: '4', createdProfile: '08/02/2022'}
  ]
```

And 2 dates `let fromDate = '24/12/2021'; let toDate = '11/02/2022';`
And i need to remove those objects which are not in range, and group those objects which are in range by weeks.
For instance result should look like this :

```
let result = [
  [
    {name: 'Karina', surname: 'Burba', id: '2', createdProfile: '17/01.2022'}
  ],
  [
    {name: 'Stepan', surname: 'German', id: '4', createdProfile: '08/02/2022'},
    {name: 'Misha', surname: 'Borovuk', id: '1', createdProfile: '11/02/2022'},
     // Because they addad on same weak
  ],
] 

let dates = [
  [
   '17/01/2022',
   '23/01/2022'
  ],
  [
   '07/02/2022',
   '13/02/2022'
  ],
]
```

But does anyone know is it possible to do without for loops, maybe with `groupBy` of `forEach`, `map`?
In order to not complicate application?
I was looking a lot and only found a few examples with `lodash` and `groupBy`

```
groupBy(objectsList, (dt) => moment(dt).week());
```

But they all use only one from `fromDate` parameter and don't use `toDate` parameter.
And also this approach doesn't allow to get rid of those items which are not in range.
Sorry for not providing any code solutions, all my ideas have lots of nested loops and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast your string-dates into actual JavaScript `Date-Objects` with `new Date('01/12/2022')`. After all of your dates are actual `Date-Objects`, you can compare them with operators: `new Date('01/12/2022') < new Date('02/12/2022') // true`. After that, you need to loop over them and split them correctly. As this is more of a math-thing, you would benefit most, if you try to solve this with regular JS methods like `map` or `foreach`. This is a fairly easy task and good practice for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> But does anyone know is it possible to do without for loops, maybe with groupBy of forEach, map?

You are probably looking for the `filter` method. It will return each item that passes a conditional test in its callback, the conditional test in your case being a date within two dates.

[Here's a link.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Try something like

```js
const results = objectsLists.filter(item => {
     return item.createdProfile.getTime() >= fromDate.getTime() &&
            item.createdProfile.getTime() <= toDate.getTime()
})
```

I don't recognize your date format and am not sure it will play nicely with JavaScript's built-in [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class. If possible, you should consider using that instead. If not, you could still use the filter method with a more convoluted conditional checking month/day/year positions in the `createdProfile` string.